# Plotting graph of a function with an imposed a condition

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have to plot a function $f(x,y,z)=\sin[x+y+z]$ with an imposed condition $\sin[y]\sin[x]=\sin[z]$. How do I plot it in Mathematica using `Plot3D`?

Answer (score 7):

The constraint defines a surface. Use colour and mesh lines to indicate the function value on that surface.

Thanks to Bob Hanlon for correcting my initially flawed implementation.

```
Legended[
 ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Sin[y] == Sin[z], 
  {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"]@Rescale[Sin[x + y + z], {-1, 1}]
   ], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, Sin[x + y + z]]]
 , 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: @BobHanlon You are correct! Thanks for noticing this mistake!

Comment: @BobHanlon If you'd like to add this to your answer, feel free to do so and I will delete mine.

Comment: Your approach is much different than mine and should remain.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] = Sin[x + y + z];

cond = Sin[x] Sin[y] == Sin[z];

Plot3D[
 Evaluate[
  f[x, y, z] /. (Solve[cond, z] /. C[1] -> 0)],
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, y, z}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Below]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html)

You can use [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) using the constraint defining the surface as the second argument and the color function to indicate the values of `Sin[x + y + z]`:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[Sin[x + y + z], 
 Sin[x] Sin[y] == Sin[z], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow" , PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

You can also use `SliceContourPlot3D` to get a similar picture (but I was not able get price control on the contours).

### [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

An alternative approach is to use `ParametricPlot3D` after solving the constraint  for `z`  (as in Bob Hanlon's answer) and using `MeshFunctions` and `ColorFunction` to indicate the values of `Sin[x + y + z]` (as in Szabolcs's answer):

```
funcs = {x, y, z} /. 
  Solve[{Sin[x] Sin[y] == Sin[z], -Pi <= x <= Pi && -Pi <= y <= Pi && -Pi <= z <= Pi}, 
    z, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0
```

> {{x, y, ConditionalExpression[-π - ArcSin[Sin[x] Sin[y]],
> (0 < x < π && -π <= y <=  0) || (-π < x < 0 && 0 <= y <= π)]},
> {x, y, ConditionalExpression[π - ArcSin[Sin[x] Sin[y]],
> (0 < x < π && 0 <= y <= π) || (-π < x < 0 && -π <= y <= 0)]},
> {x, y, ConditionalExpression[ArcSin[Sin[x] Sin[y]],
> (0 < x < π && -π <= y <= π) || (-π < x < 0 && -π <= y <= π)]}}

```
Legended[ParametricPlot3D[funcs, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MeshFunctions -> {Sin[# + #2 + #3] &}, Mesh -> {10}, 
  MeshShading -> {Automatic}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}][Sin[# + #2 + #3]] &)],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]